# Confusion in definition of class of structures and combinatorial class

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, definitions

I understand that a combinatorial class $\mathcal{A}$ is a set of objects, with a function of size $\lvert\cdot\rvert_{\mathcal{A}}:\mathcal{A}\to \mathbb{N}$. With objects of size $n$: $\mathcal{A}_n=\{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}\;:\; \lvert\alpha\rvert_{\mathcal{A}}=n\}$, and a condition of finitude $\#\mathcal{A}_n<\infty$.

In a book ["Introduction to Combinatorial Enumeration" by David G. Wagner](https://uwaterloo.ca/combinatorics-and-optimization/sites/ca.combinatorics-and-optimization/files/uploads/files/co330-notes.pdf) chapter 11, I came across the term "class of structures", and they define it as:

A class $\mathcal{A}$ associated with a finite set $X$ is another finite set $\mathcal{A}_X$, such that if $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets:

If $X\neq Y$ then $\mathcal{A}_X\cap \mathcal{A}_Y=\emptyset$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets with $\lvert X\rvert=\lvert Y\rvert$, then $\lvert\mathcal{A}_X\rvert=\lvert\mathcal{A}_Y\rvert$.

My question is whether these two definitions refer to the same thing. I am somewhat confused.

Comment: Luis, your second condition is wrong, the $X\neq Y$ should be removed.  The two definitions are different.  The first one you give is probably from the book of Flajolet and Sedgewick.  The second one looks like a "simplification" of the idea of combinatorial species.  Both are useful in enumeration.

Comment: @Martin Rubey Thanks for the correction, I already edited the question.  By the way, do you know if there is a way to link both definitions?  Or are they completely disjoint?

Comment: In general, what is the difference between using the symbolic method with combinatorial species than using it with combinatorial structures?  Is the same?

Comment: Combinatorial species keep track of the action of the symmetric group.

Comment: Crosspost at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4348045/definition-of-classes-of-structures-in-combinatorics/4348082#4348082

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you have stated the definition of "class of structures" incorrectly.
(Wagner states it correctly.) The first sentence should be: "A class $\mathcal{A}$ of structures associates to every finite set $X$ another finite set $\mathcal{A}_X$, in such a way that the following two conditions are satisfied:"

The two definitions represent different concepts. The first refers to "unlabeled objects" like partitions, binary words, or lattice paths, where the set of objects under consideration of size $n$ is finite. The second refers to "labeled objects" like graphs or permutations. For example, if $\mathcal{A}$ represents the class of graphs, then for any finite set $X$, $\mathcal{A}_X$ is the set of graphs with vertex set $X$. Roughly speaking, "combinatorial classes" correspond to ordinary generating functions and "classes of structures" correspond to exponential generating functions.

Comment: Thank you very much, an explanation like the one in your last paragraph was the one I needed